# AADB2C90006 with https-> http transition in redirect_uri

Tags: asp.net-core, google-apps, azure-ad-b2c

I have an ASP.NET Core application that uses Azure Active Directory B2C for authentication which I am deploying into a Google App Engine instance. In my Application configuration in AD B2C I have `https://<domain>/signin-oid` as my redirect URL, but when I go to sign in I get error `AADB2C90006` saying domain `http://<domain>/signin-oid` is invalid. I don't have the `http` version of this url specified anywhere in my code.

I've tried running this locally in my development environment and it works as expected. I understand that Nginx acts as a proxy in front of the Kestrel instance that starts, and I have configured SSL in my Kestrel instance to use the same certificate that the App Engine instance uses. I mention this because my suspicion lies in some sort of disconnect between the App Engine and Kestrel configurations, though it's very murky as to where the problem might be.

```
      return new WebHostBuilder()
            .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aspEnv) && !string.Equals(aspEnv,"Development"))
                {                        
                    options.ListenAnyIP(443,opt => opt.UseHttps("myfile.pfx","mypass"));
                }
            })
```

I also have this line in my `Configure` function:

```
                app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
                {
                    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
                });
```

Comment: I assume this is occurring because the web app isn't redirecting from `http` to `https` before it redirects to Azure AD B2C which is expecting a `https` reply URL. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954158/asp-net-core-2-1-no-http-https-redirection-in-app-engine) help?

Comment: I've gotten a little bit further forward with this recommendation, to the point where it redirects to the `https` address but gives me a 404 because the response from B2C is still looking for `http`. Also tried adding https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/issues/51 but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I still don't know why `http:` is coming through instead of `https:`, but I **do** have a fix for it.

In my project, I have a class called `OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup` that I picked up from the [Azure AD B2C sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/). In this class I configure the `OpenIdConnectEvents` which includes one `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` delegate, where I had some code looking for `http:` but buried in an `if` statement looking for discrepancies in the authentication policy, code which I have yet to see get called, but I digress.

My delegate now looks like this:

```cs
            public Task OnRedirectToIdentityProviderAsync(RedirectContext context)
            {
                Logger.LogInformation($"redirect URI for B2C: {context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri} !!!!!!!");

                if (context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.Contains("http:"))
                {                    
                    Logger.LogInformation("http: found in RedirectUri, replacing with https");
                    context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.Replace("http:", "https:");
                }

                //in case of error, show us the problem
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ProtocolMessage.ErrorUri))
                {
                    Logger.LogInformation("ErrorUri is empty! replacing with ErrorUri property.");
                    context.ProtocolMessage.ErrorUri = GCPSettings.ErrorUri;
                }
            }
```

Using this configuration, I was successfully able to log in to my site using Azure AD B2C.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when deploying a .NET Core app to an Azure App Service on Linux. I was able to solve it by forwarding the `XForwardedProto` header in `Startup.cs` as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54127683/848254).