# How to setup ASP.NET Core ports in an Openshift container

Tags: asp.net-core

At our company, we use Openshift and k8s. Java is a mainstream language here and everything is setup to support its deployments. I wanted to try out .NET Core after I dabbled with it a bit. More or less I was able to deploy a simple site to Openshift and everything seems to work except for one little problem.

Since the app is deployed in a reverse proxy configuration which handles HTTPS, I added the following to my `Dockerfile` file and disabled the HTTPS redirection:

```
# OCP expects the container to bind to port 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "my-web-app.dll", "--urls", "http://*:8080"]
```

I am able to navigate the different pages properly using the Openshift HTTPS URL. However, after I implemented `Authorize` and a simple cookie scheme to guard certain Razor pages, I get redirected (as I should) to the login page but the protocol is switched to `HTTP` and the browser says the site cannot be reached. If I manually change the protocol to `HTTPS`, it works again.

How should I setup the ports so this does not happen?

Answer (score 0):

Wow...just tried this answer in [ASP.NET Core 2.1 no HTTP/HTTPS redirection in App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954158/asp-net-core-2-1-no-http-https-redirection-in-app-engine?rq=1) :

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
    return next();
});
```

and it works :-)