# Http to Https redirect not working for ASPNET Core3.1 app on GCP App Engine Flex

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, https

I have deployed an ASPNET Core 3.1 app on Google's App Engine in a flex environment. The app is still accessible on both HTTP and HTTPS. I want to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS. Read in many places that apps on GCP App Engine should be configured on application level to handle http redirection I have tried **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite** but it would return too many redirects once the app is deployed on App Engine. When not using the rewriter it will have the app accessible on both protocols. I have even tried a custom middleware as instructed [here](https://joonasw.net/view/enforcing-https-in-aspnet-core) but again it would return too many redirects. Please tell me where I am wrong and how can I get it resolved. Thanks a lot.

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                //app.UseHttpsEnforcement();
                //var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps(301, 443);
                //app.UseRewriter(options);
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.              
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

**Custom middleware**

```
public static class AppBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseHttpsEnforcement(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (app == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
            }
            return app.UseMiddleware<EnforceHttpsMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```

```
 public class EnforceHttpsMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public EnforceHttpsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            HttpRequest req = context.Request;
            if (req.IsHttps == false)
            {
                string url = "https://" + req.Host + req.Path + req.QueryString;
                context.Response.Redirect(url, permanent: true);
            }
            else
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
        }
    }
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: aspnetcore 
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So fortunately I was able to resolve it. The app needed some configuration in order properly able to understand the request. See Natthapol Vanasrivilai's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954158/asp-net-core-2-1-no-http-https-redirection-in-app-engine). The solution was targeted at NET Core 2.1 but it turns out to be working in NET Core 3.1 as well.